# python twisted transport.write never sends data

Tags: python, twisted.client

I have a server which is loosely based on the Twisted example chat server. It works with telnet. Now I want a client to connect to it.I copied the sample one-time client. The problem is the server never receives the "hello" string which is supposed to start the "conversation". I read in the FAQ that a common mistake is to block the reactor from running but I cannot see where I could be doing that in the code below. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint

class Greeter(Protocol):
    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        self.transport.write("%s\n" % msg)

class GreeterFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Greeter()

def gotProtocol(p):
    p.sendMessage("hello")
    reactor.callLater(1, p.sendMessage, "/p2")
    reactor.callLater(2, p.transport.loseConnection)

point = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", 8123)
d = point.connect(GreeterFactory())
d.addCallback(gotProtocol)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Can you post your server implementation as well?

Answer (score 2):

OK. I hope this helps someone else. My problem above was that my server (which used lineReceived):

```
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print "line received: %s" % line
        if self.state == "GETNAME":
            self.handle_GETNAME(line)
        else:
            self.handle_CHAT(line)
```

expected a carriage-return AND linefeed. So by changing my sendMessage above to:

```
    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        self.transport.write("%s\r\n" % msg)
```

it now works magically! So frustratingly simple.